# automapper map collections with action

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, automapper

I have the following code

```
IList<ConfigurationDto> result = new List<ConfigurationDto>();
foreach (var configuration in await configurations.ToListAsync())
{
    var configurationDto = _mapper.Map<ConfigurationDto>(configuration);
    configurationDto.FilePath = _fileStorage.GetShortTemporaryLink(configuration.FilePath);
    result.Add(configurationDto);
}
return result;
```

How can I use automapper instead if foreach? I can map collection, but how to call `_fileStorage.GetShortTemporaryLink` for each item?

I have looked at [AfterMap](http://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Before-and-after-map-actions.html) but I don't know how to get `FilePath` from `dest` and map it to `src` one by one. Can I use automapper for that?

```
public class ConfigurationDto
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Version { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreateDateTime { get; set; }
    public long Size { get; set; }
    public string FilePath { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `IValueResolver` interface to configure your map to map a property from a function. Something like the sample bellow.

```
public class CustomResolver : IValueResolver<Configuration, ConfigurationDto, string>
{
    private readonly IFileStorage fileStorage;

    public CustomResolver(IFileStorage fileStorage)
    {
        _fileStorage= fileStorage;
    }

    public int Resolve(Configuration source, ConfigurationDto destination, string member, ResolutionContext context)
    {
        return _fileStorage.GetShortTemporaryLink(source.FilePath);
    }
}
```

> Once we have our `IValueResolver` implementation, we’ll need to tell AutoMapper to use this custom value resolver when resolving a specific destination member. We have several options in telling AutoMapper a custom value resolver to use, including:
>
> - `MapFrom<TValueResolver>`
> - `MapFrom(typeof(CustomValueResolver))`
> - `MapFrom(aValueResolverInstance)`

Then you should configure your map to use the custom resolver for mapping the `FilePath` property on `ConfigurationDto`.

```
var configuration = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => cfg.CreateMap<Configuration, ConfigurationDto>()
                   .ForMember(dest => dest.FilePath, opt => opt.MapFrom<CustomResolver>()));
```

You can see more about custom value resolvers at this link: http://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Custom-value-resolvers.html